# Application dependencies (another apps)

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-zookeeper

We need to deploy our 4 applications (3 spring boot apps and 1 zookeper) with docker stack. As our DevOps guy told us, there is no way how to define in docker stack which application will be depending on another like in docker compose, so we as developers need to solve it in code.

Can you tell me how to do that or what is the best way? One of our applications have to be started as first because that app manage database (migration and so on). Next can start other applications when database is prepared. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It is an anti-pattern to have a shared database among several applications.

Comment: our applications in company work like that I can nothing to do with that unfortunately.

Comment: Why are they different applications, because apparently they aren’t.

Comment: @M.Deinum there are few aplication which share database because contains static data.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run all the 4 applications in one docker container, you can refer to this post[Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

if you want to **docker compose** the 4 applications, you can refer to this post [startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/), it use **depends_on** your other app images

no matter what the way is, you must write a script to check if your first app has already finish to manage the database, you can refer **wait-for-postgres.sh** to learn how to use **sleep** in shell to repeatedly check your first app status

the more precisely way i can suggest one is for example:

1. put a shared static variable to false
   public static boolean is_app_start = false;
2. when you finish to manage your database, change this value to true;
3. write a **@RequestMapping("/is_app_start")** in your controller to return this value
4. use **curl** in your shell script to check the value